# How can i find out which form mode is used from hook_form_FORM_ID_alter?

Tags: 8, forms

I have created a new form mode (in the UI at `admin/structure/display-modes`) for a custom entity (form mode is entitled `apply`) and added `apply` to the form handler classes in the entity class.

The form is built and returned in a Controller, and specifies the form mode.

`$form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($entity, 'apply');`

Now I would like to be able to determine from a `hook_form_alter` whether this form is being displayed using the `apply` form mode, but I cannot work out how that is available from `$form` or `$form_state`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [EntityFormInterface::getOperation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormInterface.php/function/EntityFormInterface%3A%3AgetOperation/8.4.x):

```
function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // only continue if this is for form mode "apply"
  if ($form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation() !== 'apply') {
    return;
  }

  // do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer doesn't check form mode, but it checks the operation instead. To validate on form mode, you can use something like this:

```
function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormDisplay $formDisplay */
  $formDisplay = $form_state->getStorage()['form_display'];
  
  // Only continue if this is for form mode "apply".
  if ($formDisplay->getMode() !== 'apply') {
    return;
  }

  // do stuff

}
```

Comment: The second parameter of getForm($entity, 'apply') specifies the operation. For entity forms operation and form mode are identical. This is defined in the entity class as form handler, as explained at the beginning of the question.